# Unstable 96V DC to 3.3V Supply

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, ldo, 3.3v

So I've got a huge battery at 96VDC with a couple of electric motors hooked up to it that can draw huge amounts of current -- up to 600 amps.  I need to power a few small electronics for a data acquisition system off this battery.  If I were to guess, these components wouldn't draw more than 50mA.

I don't have the battery yet but if I were to guess, this 96V won't be very stable as the current draw is going to surpass the rated capacity of these batteries.

What's the best way to get a 3.3V supply rail off this type of battery?  Would an LDO be the best solution here?  Any suggestions on filtering the input, knowing that there will be these motors also hooked up to the battery?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any safe way to tap into the battery to get a lower voltage?

Comment: 'as the current draw is going to surpass the rated capacity of these batteries' easy there buddy.... Don't want one of these things exploding....

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you could find an LDO with a 100V input rating, you would have (96-3.3)=92.7V across the LDO.  With 50mA through it you would have 4.64 Watts of dissipation in the LDO.  Not exactly practical.

A buck converter at 3.4% duty cycle is challenging as well, but you might get it to work.

I would look at a small flyback converter and use the turns ratio of the coupled inductor to get a reasonable duty cycle.

If this is a one-off project you might be able to get a demo board with a flyback intended to work from the AC line and modify it to handle your input range. You could of course bypass the input bridge rectifier as well.

Comment: This cheap chinese AC adapter to 3.3V @ 500mA from eBay should work on 96VDC.  http://www.ebay.com/itm/AC-DC-Power-Regulated-Supply-Adaptor-90-240V-To-3-3V-500mA-Switched-Regulator-/390775106579?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5afc02ec13

Comment: @BrianOnn the question was for 96VDC and not AC like the adapter you liked

Comment: @kimliv Brian is right, it would work on AC or DC input and the bridge would allow it to use the internal capacitor to hold up the supply during brief dips. The internal cap could be paralleled with a bigger one if the dips were too long duration.

Comment: "A buck converter at 3.4% duty cycle is challenging as well, but you might get it to work." I once did a 400V to 15V buck converter, which has a similar 3.75% duty cycle, and it worked just fine. I used a high-voltage PNP transistor as the switching element.

Comment: @BrianOnn Great idea.  The only hitch might be that the controller ICs in these flybacks sometimes have UVLO protection that kicks in around 80VAC or so, which is 113V on the DC bus.  Most of them probably don't even have UVLO or have it set much lower, but if a particular adapter doesn't work that might be the reason why.